# Getting "Error: data.map is not a function" error in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, next.js

I just don't get it, so this fetch works as expected:

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  return res.json()
}

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await getData()

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid gap-3 grid-cols-fluid">
        {data.map((item: any) => (
          <p key={''}>{item.title}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But on the other hand, this example does not work:

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/frames/us-gaap/AssetsCurrent/USD/CY2021Q4I.json')
  return res.json()
}

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await getData()

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid gap-3 grid-cols-fluid">
        {data.map((item: any) => (
          <p key={''}>{item.label}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It always shows:

> Error: data.map is not a function

Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using use `data.map()`, you are assuming the result you are getting from the API is an array. For the first one, it's the case as the data look like this:

```js
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  // ...
]
```

But the second response looks like this:

```js
{
  //...
  label: "Assets, Current",
  // ...
  data: [
    {
      accn: "0001104659-21-152249",
      cik: 1750,
      entityName: "AAR CORP",
      loc: "US-IL",
      end: "2021-11-30",
      val: 946700000,
    },
    // ...
  ],
};
```

Which is an object that contains a `data` array as you can see above. So you wanna loop over it, use it like so:

```js
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/frames/us-gaap/AssetsCurrent/USD/CY2021Q4I.json"
  );
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {
  //  grab the data array and other values as you would like inside the object
  const { data, ccp } = await getData();

  return (
    <div>
      CCP: {ccp}
      <div className="grid gap-3 grid-cols-fluid">
        {data.map((item: any) => (
          <p key={item.entityName}>{item.entityName}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```